# Convert multiline bash script to an one line

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have script like this:

```
for f in *
do
    #if condition
    if [[ -d $f ]]; then
        echo "$f is a directory";
    else
        echo "$f is not a directory";
    fi
done
```

Is it possible to convert multiple script into 1 line like this? (maybe I need to delete `#` comment statement(s)).

```
for f in *; do  if [[ -d $f ]]; then  echo "$f is a directory"; else  echo "$f is not a directory"; fi done
```

I can change for statement syntax in above script like:

1. `for f in *`
2. `for f in *;`
3. `for f in *;do`

Same applies to `if` condition. In all the cases it should generate a proper 1 line. What could be the automated way to do this?

Comment: what's the advantage? On the contrary, writing compound commands like this in one line actually harms readability.

Comment: You are right, but  case where automation is required  needs 1 liner, instead of writing a large script.

Comment: If you know about `plink` which is a commandline `putty` version works perfectly with command provided at commandline. I mean executing script compared with command is quite tedious and erroneous using `plink`.

Comment: If it has problems with multi-line commands, then, no, `plink` doesn't work "perfectly". I have never had any problems with multiline commands using the `ssh` tool on Linux systems.

Comment: I will give you another example, If you ever worked on networking devices such as Cisco Firewall, Cisco Router, Mipu Router etc. These type of N/W devices only understand commands, no script. Also, if we fire script on target machine its internally get copied somewhere on target system and for that it should have space.

Comment: you seem to have some  serious confusion. There is a difference between a script and multi-line command. The former is a file, the latter is just a multi-line command. If the target system understands bash, it *will* understand multiline commands just fine. Do your Cisco devices understand bash? If no, what is the relevance of those to this question?

Comment: Yes Cisco device understand it.

Comment: Then they understand multiline commands.

Comment: You realize that both the one-line version and the multiline  version can be pasted directly into the terminal, right? Neither one of those is a script, they are both commands than can be run directly in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing bash in oneliners is a hard task...

Anyway as a starting point, here goes a suggestion to cover very specific situations like the one presented

```
perl -p0e '
    s/#.*//; 
    s/;?\s+(do|done|then|else|fi)\s+/ ; $1 /g '
```

Comment: Yeah, writing generic program for this problem is difficult, but this is fine example for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
awk '{ printf "%s", $0 }' script.txt
```

Comment: Executes the awk command in quotes with input from script.txt. More from the awk manual ... I am busy ...